# DNS in Twenty-One Hours

Tags: networking, dns

I want the equivalent online resource to DNS in Twenty-One Days.  I need one evening's reading that will explain what the different record types do, how do propagation and caching work, what is an SoA, etc.

I don't want anything that begins by explaining what DNS is.

Can anybody please point me in the right direction to find some online 'DNS for Geniuses' guide, please?

Comment: @purplej0kr Why are you just giving invalid edits to all the questions you see? Just to get a 2 points? I wonder why your edits are even get approved. http://stackoverflow.com/users/3302887/purplej0kr?tab=reputation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [DNS for Rocket Scientists](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/)

It does start with a very brief "What DNS is" but you can easily skip that.

You can also check out [Records 101](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/s0306/res/recs.html) which gives a good overview of the different record types - the examples are specific to DNSMadeEasy though.

Answer (score 2):

I keep [DNS and BIND](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001582/) on my bedside table. It was good to get me going (I used the TOC and skipped the "What is DNS" bits), and it keeps on giving me confidence and a helping hand.

I don't normally buy soot-on-dead-trees books, but this one is a rare exception that has repaid me many times over.

Answer (score 2):

The definitive source, and quite readable (IMO):

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt

Answer (score 1):

When I set up DNS for the first time I read [DNS HOWTO](http://www.langfeldt.net/DNS-HOWTO/BIND-9/). It worked pretty well for me.